# Can I create a Middleware class in one app that handles requests in other apps on the site

Tags: python, django, middleware

In reading the,
[Middlware Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order)
I can see I can write a middleware class that will see and has access to every request in my app, which is good.

What if I want my Middleware to see and handle all requests in all apps on the site?

If I Subclass a core Middleware class, will that then become the base middleware that all apps will call?  Is there some other way to achieve this?

If I subclass one of the Middleware classes, where do I put it in my app?

Comment: Each middleware processes every request to your Django process regardless of app, are you expecting custom middleware to only be run for requests to views in a particular app?

Comment: Thanks that answers one question.  Yes I want my custom middlware to run for every request regardless of app.  The question now is where do I put my CustomeMiddleware class?  I see the MIDDLWARE list in settings.py  if my app is dose and I have a folder 'midleware' in that app I am guessing I place my CustomMiddleware in that folder and update mysite settings with something like 'dose.middleware.CutomMiddlware', yes?

Comment: Yes, although the exact path may be slightly different. See the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware

Comment: Yes thanks I actually cited the docs in my question but that doesn't give an example.  I think my problem now is defining the CustomMiddlware in the module so it can be loaded.

Comment: You need the full python path to your middleware class/factory. If you have an app named "dose" containing a file named "middleware.py" and you define your middleware in that file then `'dose.middleware.CutomMiddlware'` would be correct - if you want to use a folder named "middleware" instead then you need to ensure it contains a file named `__init__.py` and you need to include the file name where your middleware is defined too

Comment: Ok tried that, and moved my CustomMiddleware.py up to the /dose/ folder and restarted.  Got django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'mysite.wsgi.application' could 
not be loaded; Error importing module.

Comment: What's the name of the middleware class in that file? The path to your middleware should look something like this based on your comment `'dose.CustomMiddleware.YourMiddlewareClassName'`, replace "YourMiddlewareClassName" with the name of your middleware class or factory function